# How to get character like go down stairs in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I want to get a character from string but the path is like going downstairs in Google Sheets

The string is like:

```
y    C    I    6    8    V    5
~5   Z    n    I    L    w    f
V    ~s   i    w    J    d    _
o    R    ~4   2    i    v    f
9    ^    j    ~h   r    u    #
Z    y    Q    7    ~1   u    a
T    t    z    u    _    ~!   Q
G    Y    n    r    *    t    ~^
J    A    l    v    F    j    d
a    2    l    -    y    O    B
h    B    w    %    n    a    4
M    t    _    P    D    W    a
```

And  expect the output is:

```
5    s    4    h    1    !    ^
```

I put ~ in front of the character that demo the path I want to get.
The logic is I will find the first column which cell is 5 and then get start from that cell.

Example sheet link
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UQEGEl_rqAMFePDAGoueTI47xF8T_DyrvJ3de5pkLRA/edit#gid=306981885

I tried auto-fill but it could only incrementally either row or column. And I hope to incremental both row and column.

Comment: can you explain the logic of it? why that one is right but not this one? https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHr1f.png

Comment: I would like to find the first column which value is 5. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
={INDIRECT("A"&MATCH(5, A1:A14, 0)),
  INDIRECT("B"&MATCH(5, A1:A14, 0)+1),
  INDIRECT("C"&MATCH(5, A1:A14, 0)+2),
  INDIRECT("D"&MATCH(5, A1:A14, 0)+3),
  INDIRECT("E"&MATCH(5, A1:A14, 0)+4),
  INDIRECT("F"&MATCH(5, A1:A14, 0)+5),
  INDIRECT("G"&MATCH(5, A1:A14, 0)+6)}
```

[image: 0]

---

for a large scale scenario you can use this one and drag it to the right:

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH(5, $A1:$A14, 0)+COLUMN()-1, COLUMN(), 4))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Thank you so much. That's what I need especially for a large scale scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it with an array formula if you want to:

```
=ArrayFormula(hlookup(column(A2:G13),{column(A2:G13);A2:G13},match(5,A2:A13,0)+column(A2:G13)))
```

[image]